# Is it possible to upgrade an MVC 1 project to MVC 3 and use the Razor view engine along side the original one?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

The original view engine being the .aspx files with the <% %> riddled all over. I kind of want to move away from that, but I want the old code files to still work fine as I migrate.

Are there any good methods for this and/or snags I should be aware of?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web forms view engine and razor view engine in the same project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743904/web-forms-view-engine-and-razor-view-engine-in-the-same-project)

Comment: @GeorgeStocker what about the upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to upgrade from v1 to v3 directly using a tool.  You will have to first upgrade using this [tool](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2010/03/10/migrating-asp-net-mvc-1-0-applications-to-asp-net-mvc-2-rtm.aspx) and then use [this](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/59008) version to get it to MVC3.

You can also use both view engines together without a problem as seen [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingRazorViewsAndWebFormsMasterPagesWithASPNETMVC3.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use a mixture of both engines, and you can include ascx partial views into Razor views, which is helpful during the transition.

aspx and cshtml (Razor) views cannot share a master page, so ultimately you have to have two masters (one for the old, one for the new).  However, you can generally refactor most of your master page into a handful of ascx files, which you can then use with both the 'old' and the 'new' master pages.